# is there an event corresponding to changing a player position manually?

Tags: spotify

I would like to prevent a user to manually change position of the current track.
my idea was to intercept this event :

```
data: Object
contextclear: false
curcontext: false
curtrack: false
playstate: false
repeat: false
shuffle: false
volume: false
__proto__: Object
type: "playerStateChanged"
__proto__: Object
```

but everytime I click on play/pause, this event is also catched.
is there a special type of event for this action ?

many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Currently, there is no way to disable the seek bar from getting actions from a user. Soundrop solves this by syncing the play time continuously from their backend.

This feature is under consideration.

Answer (score 0):

That event is fired whenever the current context, current track, play state, repeat, shuffle or volume changes, as you can see by the properties. Checking which property is set to `true` lets you know what actually happened.

As for intercepting event to block them, I doubt that'd work. The JS events for the player are more like notifications - unless you sort of "hack" it by manually setting the playback state back to what you want it to be, you can't really block that sort of thing.